# Force a window to stay always on top in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Question pretty much stands for itself.
To just right click always on top and have window in focus all the time. (on top of other windows no metter if you click somewhere else, on desktop, taskbar, explorer, etc..) Some useful tool, or some other suggestion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Windows 7 can't do that. But you can do it with a help of a program which is called [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/).
Go and download [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/) which is actually a program for virtual desktops. After you downloaded the program right click on a window, select Dexpot and choose always on top. There is also a option to make a window transparent.

**Here a screenshot:**
[image: Dexpot Always on Top]
,

Comment: Erm, it's not working for me. I've installed dexpot, I see the dexpot menu (as in the screenshot) but the "Always on Top" does nothing, it never seems to select.

Comment: Wich OS are you using, I have tested it on Vista (32bit), 7,8 and 8.1 (32 and 64)?